# Web SQL sync using a GoogleDocs spreadsheet?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, synchronization, google-docs-api, web-sql

I need to sync the WebDB of an extension I'm building, and was thinking about using a GoogleDocs spreadsheet as storage, so the extension should be able to read/write the "file" to keep the sync. (each line of the spreadsheet would be a DB record )

Is this feasible, or there are perhaps better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

very interesting idea. but u'll have perfomance problem. Google api need oauth for authorization process which is in server side. so your server has to load data from google then parse it and send to client.
mysql would do much better performance.